# Dynamic query Execute Insert with 2 parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
create table #TempDadosExport 
    (defprodutoid int, nome varchar(250), Categoria varchar(250),tipoorigem varchar(250),Campanha varchar(250), PopUpId int);

set @sql = 'SELECT * from #Temp where ' + (SELECT Condicao FROM TBL_PDOC_SFA_PopUps_Principal WHERE PopUp_Id = @countTable); insert into #TempDadosExport(defprodutoid, nome, Categoria,tipoorigem,Campanha)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

But I need to add `@countTable` to `PopUpId` column but I can't do it with the Insert and Values because I am using an execute sql, is it possible to insert them at the same time in the same table??

Comment: That's not a valid string, much less a valid query. Is this trying to insert data, return data or insert the results of a query?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use dynamic SQL either. `INSERT` can insert the results of other queries, eg `INSER INTO T1 (col1) SELECT col1 FROM ....`

Comment: it's best practise to name columns so replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT Col1, col2 etc`

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to understand your question with a weak description and bad formatted code, but if I am assuming correctly your current script is working well but you also need to add the PopID to your insert (passing it as parameter)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @CountTable INT
 DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)

 CREATE TABLE #TempDadosExport (
    defprodutoid INT, 
    nome varchar(250), 
    Categoria varchar(250),
    tipoorigem varchar(250),
    Campanha varchar(250), 
    PopUpId int)

SET @sql = N'
    SELECT 
        defprodutoid, 
        nome, 
        Categoria,
        tipoorigem,
        Campanha, 
        @PopUpId 
    FROM #Temp' 

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'
WHERE ' + Condicao 
FROM TBL_PDOC_SFA_PopUps_Principal 
WHERE PopUp_Id = @countTable

SET @ParamDefinition = N'@PopUpID INT'

INSERT #TempDadosExport(defprodutoid, nome, Categoria,tipoorigem,Campanha, PopUpId)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDefinition, @PopUpID = @CountTable
```